# Truncate long labels on xaxis when using plotly in R

Tags: r, graph, charts, plotly, label

I would like to know if there's a way to truncate the xaxis' labels when using plotly in R, or to change the graph area/label area proportions. I don't want to hide the labels, I just want to show the beginning of them, but I do want the graph area to be bigger than it is right now (please look at image by clicking on the link below). If I change the size of the plot, this does't change the graph area/label area proportions. Thank you.

bar_plotly_R

[image: 1]